# How to save data in many to many relation without duplicate in my Card table [Entity Framework]

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I have a problem. I cannot save cards without duplicates.

I have 3 tables a Deck, Card table and a CardDeck table which is the junction table.

The goal is to store a deck in the database without the cards being duplicated.

Table Card

```
    namespace MTG_Deck.Models
    {
        public class Card
        {
            [Key]
            public int CardId { get; set; }
    
            public string Name { get; set; }
    
            public string Text { get; set; }
    
            public string Type { get; set; }
    
            public string SetName { get; set; }
    
            public string Artist { get; set; }
    
            public string ManaCost { get; set; }
    
            public string Rarity { get; set; }
    
            public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    
            public string Toughness { get; set; }
    
            public string Power { get; set; }
    
            public string id { get; set; }
    
            public virtual ICollection<DeckCard> Decks { get; set; }
     

   }
}
```

Table Deck

```
namespace MTG_Deck.Models
    {
        public class Deck
        {
            [Key]
            public int DeckId { get; set; }
    
            [Required]
            public string Name { get; set; }
    
            [DataType(DataType.Date)]
            public DateTime CreateAt { get; set; }
    
            public User User { get; set; }
    
            public virtual ICollection<DeckCard> Cards { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

Table CardDeck

```
namespace MTG_Deck.Models
{
    public class DeckCard
    {
        public int DeckID { get; set; }
        public int CardID { get; set; }

        public Deck Deck { get; set; }
        public Card Card { get; set; }

    }
}
```

CardDeckRequest contains the content of the request.

```
namespace MTG_Deck.Models
{
    public class CardDeckRequest
    {
        [Required]
        public int UserID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Token { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public Deck Deck { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MinLength(5, ErrorMessage = "The deck must contain 60 cards.")]
        public List<Card> Cards { get; set; }
    }   
}
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Add([FromBody] CardDeckRequest request)
        {
            User user = _context.User.Where(u => u.Token == request.Token).FirstOrDefault<User>();
            if (user == null) {
                var error = new string[] {"You have to be connected to create a deck!"};
                BadRequest(new { errors = new { success = error } });
            }
            List<DeckCard> deckList = new List<DeckCard>();
            if (ModelState.IsValid) {
                request.Deck.User = user;
                foreach (var item in request.Cards)
                {
                    Card card = _context.Card.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name == item.Name);
                    
                    if (card == null) {
                        card = item;
                        Console.WriteLine("coucou");
                    }
                    DeckCard deckCard = new DeckCard {
                        Card = card,
                        Deck = request.Deck
                    };
                    deckList.Add(deckCard);
                }
                _context.DeckCard.AddRange(deckList);
                _context.SaveChanges();

                var error = new string[] {"Your deck has been successfully saved."};
                return Ok(new { errors = new { success = error } });
            }
            return BadRequest(ModelState.ToDictionary(
                kvp => kvp.Key,
                kvp => kvp.Value.Errors.Select(e => e.ErrorMessage).ToArray()
            ));
        }
```

Comment: You're not exactly the first one to ask this. Usually, the most simple and effective solution is to just replace the `DeckCard` records. There should be some duplicate question telling this.

Comment: I would think the junction table would only store deck id and card id, why does the model have a Deck and Card  properties?

Comment: The DeckCard table needs just to hold the ID's of Card table and Deck table. I think the problem is with the other two properties (Card and Deck) that you have in this table. Try to put the "virtual" keyword in front of these properties, or comment them. And in your Add action, just assign the IDs to the DeckCard. I think it should work.

Comment: The previous two commenters don't seem to be aware of how EF works.